# Alert message for deadline as a reminder

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2014

I have a wpf(windows) application 
And I have a sql server data table with Values StartDate, EndDate, ReminderDate.
For that I want to apply a popup message box automatically when ReminderDate == Today.
ReminderDate is 15 days prior to EndaDate.
I tried few methods but wasn't able to get the message correctly.

This is the one I tried.

Any samples are much appreciated.

```
 string todayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
 string reminderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15).ToString();

        string date2 = reader["ReminderDate"].ToString();
        string regNo = reader["RegistrationNo"].ToString();

        DateTime expiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["ReminderDate"]);

        if (expiryDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Renew Revenue / Insurance", "Renew Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
       }
        else if (expiryDate.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(15))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Revenue Insurance Due in 15 Days ", "Renew", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
       }
```

Comment: Why do you set `expirtyDate` variable to `"ReminderDate" ` value. Shouldn't be like this?


`DateTime expiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["EndDate"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using System.DateTime.Now.Date.
Note that `expiryDate.Date` may not be equal to `DateTime.Now.Date` because the Time may differ.

For example:

`expiryDate.Date` = 1/29/2019 01:24:36 AM

AND

`DateTime.Now.Date` = 1/29/2019 12:00:00 AM

Comment: `Date` is the date component, it ignores the time.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to answer without seeing your machine settings, but I suspect you're on US culture or something. Try this:

```
DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["ReminderDate"], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```